# How to get Material-UI's <TextField/> to return correctly with ref='' like <input/> in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs, material-ui

With the following method:

```
  handleClick(event) {
    const inputText = this.refs.inputText
    console.log(inputText.value.trim())
  }
```

I am trying to get Material-UI's `<TextField/>` to return the input text correctly with ref like the `<input/>` can with `<button/>` triggering it:

```
  <input
    className='form-control'
    placeholder='Input Text'
    ref='inputText'
    type='text'
  />

  <button
    onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}
  >
```

And I attempted the following with `<TextField/>`, but it returns as `undefined`. How can I get it to return inputted text correctly like the `<input/>` above?

```
  <TextField
    hint='Enter text'
    className='form-control'
    ref='inputText'
    type='text'
  />
```

Comment: that textfield is an abstraction, meaning it is it's own react component which you cannot place a ref on. Use the `onChange={}` to get a returned value when changed. Specifically, with redux you would just update the value on every `onChange`, and when you fire `handleClick`, just check that prop.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Sorry but could you show an example of it with Redux? So I can accept the answer as well.

Comment: No problem, see my answer below. Note: I did not show the action creator and reducer to update the `textFieldValue`, I am assuming you know how to do that. Please leave a comment if you need to see them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

Set up your textfield with a `value` and `onChange` function that are hooked into redux itself, where the `onChange` function just updates the `value`.

So you'd have something like this :

```
   <TextField
       value={this.props.textFieldValue}
       onChange={this.props.textFieldChange}
```

Where the `textFieldChange` is an action that simply updates the `textFieldValue`. Most forms in redux will work something like this. Keep in mind the names i made up for those props and action are just for example. If you  have a big form you might want to consider have part of the state tree dedicated to the form itself where you have :

```
state: {
    form: {
       textField:   ...your textfield value here,
       name:  ...,
       whateverElse: ...
   }
 };
```

I like doing this with redux because I can make that architect form part of the state to look like the json payload of wherever I'm sending it to, so there I can just send the form went I want to send it.

Anyways, back to this example. When you click your `handleClick` now. All you need to do is this to get the value:

```
handleClick(event) {
   console.log(this.props.textFieldValue.trim());
}
```

Because the textfield is updated with every change, you always have access to it in your state. This also gives you flexibility over the `refs` approach, because if you use `refs` you will have a lot harder of a time getting access to that form in other components. With this approach, all the information is on your state so you can access it anytime, as long as you manage your props.

Comment: Appreciate the in-depth info! Do you mind showing a full on a reducer and also on the `state:{form:{}}`? If I update on thing, it seems like it loses state on other properties.

Comment: do you think it is safe to use this approach for input[type=password]?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onChange={} to get the value:

```
_onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

<TextField
    onChange={this._onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution than using onchange event, we get directly the value of the input created by material-ui textField :

```
  create(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = this.refs.inputText.input.value;
    alert(name);
  }

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.create = this.create.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <form>
            <TextField ref="inputText" hintText="" floatingLabelText="Your name" /><br/>
            <RaisedButton label="Create" onClick={this.create} primary={true} />
          </form>
    )}
```

hope this helps.